# How to repair a PPA to not get "The repository is not signed."

Tags: apt, ppa, repository

I created [a PPA for some packages I've written](https://launchpad.net/%7Ebrandizzi/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). Then I added its keys in my machine:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 03BBACDA765F39D9A14EEDE4425F3F9343B40373
  ...
gpg: Número total processado: 1
gpg:               importados: 1
```

Then I tried to add the PPA repo, and got this:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:brandizzi/ppa
   ...                                                                             
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/brandizzi/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                         
  403  Forbidden [IP: ...]
   ...
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/brandizzi/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I know I can force APT to use an unsigned repository, or add `[trusted=yes]` in my local `source.list` files but I'd like to see the commands above working without any of these approaches (which seem heavy-handed and less secure than possible.)

What should I change in my PPA to avoid this error?

Comment: Seems to be temporary issue. I have added your PPA just now without error messages.

Comment: Yes, just tested the installation. Everything went good.

Comment: Oh, good news. I was scared! If you will, it would be nice to have the temporary aspect of the issue as an answer to be accepted for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After about 30 minutes from package upload I was able to add the PPA and install package from it.

So it was temporary issue. I think it was caused by GPG key generation and distribution for reusing by APT.